# ¿Cómo quedarme con los 4 últimos dígitos de los datos de una columna excel en R?

Tags: r

Tengo una columna "Tractor" que toma valores de la forma ECO01006 , es decir, tenemos siempre el prefijo ECO0, y a continuación 4 dígitos que van cambiando. Necesito quedarme con los 4 últimos dígitos. Había pensado en separar en 2 columnas por el 0, pero no sé como hacerlo, pues implementando la orden `separate` con `sep=0` me elimina todos los 0 que haya inclusive en los 4 dígitos que necesito.
De todas formas pienso que debe haber una orden más sencilla que directamente se quede con los 4 últimos dígitos de los datos de una columna.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tomado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963898/extracting-the-last-n-characters-from-a-string-in-r

```
# definimos función
substrRight <- function(x, n)
{
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

#aplicamos a un ejemplo como el tuyo
tractor<-c('ECO01006', 'ECO01106', 'ECO01007', 'ECO01006', 'ECO03006')
substrRight(tractor,4)
[1] "1006" "1106" "1007" "1006" "3006"
```

Answer (score 1):

Si revisamos la ayuda de `separate()` podemos leer acerca del parámetro `sep`:

> If numeric, sep is interpreted as character positions to split at.

Es decir, si en vez de una cadena, pasamos un número este es tomado como la posición  a partir de la cual dividir una columna:

```
data.frame(Tractor = "ECO01006") %>% 
  separate(Tractor, sep=4, into=c('prefijo', 'numero'))

  prefijo numero
1    ECO0   1006
```